# What is the basis of the linear space $U=\{A\in \mathcal{M}_{3\times 3}\,|\,A=A^T\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following linear space $U=\{A\in \mathcal{M}_{3\times 3}\,|\,A=A^T\}$ (the space of symetric matices of order 3). I wonder what is the basis of this space. I was thinking about the following candidates:
$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $A_2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$,
$A_3=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$,
$A_4=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$,
$A_5=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$.
My idea is to obtain a matrix $B$ such that $b_{ij}=1$, i.e., 
$$A_1+…+A_5=B.$$
The set $B(U)=\{A_i, \,i=1…5\}$ is linearly independent, but the question is, if it is a basis? If I consider any linear combination 
$$c_1A_1+…+c_5A_5,$$
then in the result matrix I will have coefficients $c_1,…c_5$, while a matrix from $U$ has nine coefficients, which means that some of them will be duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, a vector space usually has infinitely many basis. But your set isn't one of them, because the matrix$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$cannot be expressed as a linear combination of its elements.

Forget your matrix $A_2$ and use$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$instead. *Then* you will have *a* basis.

Answer (score 0):

The space of all $n\times n $ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ that are symmetric has dimension $\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: But upper triangular or lower triangular matrices are not symmetric.

Comment: The condition that i have mentioned makes them symmetric